# Does this synthesis of dimethylmercury require anything else?

Tags: organic-chemistry, mercury

I've seen that dimethylmercury can be made using sodium amalgam and methyl iodide. Are those the only chemicals needed or does the reaction require a solvent or application of heat or anything else like that? Or will the reaction take place just by mixing the two? Not trying to make it but concerned about possible accidental contamination.

Comment: I don't think we're gonna give you preparative receipt for a serious poison. BTW you cannot **mix**  sodium amalgam and methyl iodide - reaction takes place on the interface between them. Contact between them is enough for reaction to take place, as mentioned in earlier post.

Comment: The link you provided seems to answer my question. I was hoping there was more to it but thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you don't want to make it, this should be enough. What temperature, solvent etc. to use for actual synthesis of pure compound with good yield aren't really relevant otherwise.

Comment: Why do people keep being worried about such unlikely reaction, seems to be beyond me...